# Can this underdetermined equation be solved?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

We have the following equation **p**=(1+s)**p**(**A**+**dl**) where **p** is an unknown vector, **d** as well as **l** are given vectors, s a constant and **A** a diagonal matrix. Would it be possible to solve this equation without an extra one? Or is it simply underdetermined?
Could it be solved with a Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the vectors/matrices here? I can't make the dimensions make sense given the current multiplication.

Comment: I am sorry, there has been a misunderstanding. I have edited the question.

Comment: Define $\lambda=(1+s)^{-1}$ and $M=(A+dl)^T$ then the equation becomes 
$$Mp=\lambda p$$
Does that look familiar?

Comment: Yes! An eigenfunction